# Using Nexus as feature repository

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

Is there a way to add a secured Nexus repository as feature repository to Apache Karaf?

I tried to run the command:

```
karaf@root()> feature:repo-add http://<user>:<password>@<my-repository>
```

But I get the following error:

```
Adding feature url http://<user>:<password>@<my-repository> Error executing command: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://<user>:<password>@<my-repository>
```

I'm using Apache Karaf 3.0.0.

Thanks,
Mickael

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple.

Install Maven on the server on which Karaf is running and configure it. Generally, you will configure it through the file `settings.xml` present in `~/.m2`. The credentials for accessing the Nexus repository are indicated in the file.

Finally, instead of using an HTTP URL for referencing your feature, use a Maven URL of the form:

```
mvn:<groupId>/<artifactId>/<version>/xml/features
```

The feature will be resolved through Maven.

Comment: yep, this is it, make sure you use maven coordinates when working with the nexus :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own Maven repository to **org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories**.

1. `config:edit org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn`
2. `config:property-set org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories http://your.nexus.repo/here`
3. `config:update`